# "mvn spring-boot:run" works, but executing a Spring Boot fat jar fails

Tags: maven, spring-boot, proguard

**Short description of my problem**: `mvn spring-boot:run` allows me to run my Spring Boot application without issues, while `mvn package spring-boot:repackage` produces a self executable fat jar that fails to start with the exception `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.`

*I have the suspect that the problem is related to Proguard, however I'm not sure.*

I've already spent hours reading related problems on Stack Overflow (this exception seems a common problem), however I didn't find the cause of the error neither the solution. I also don't understand why I should have to modify my code (like in a lot of discussion that I've read) considering that with `mvn spring-boot:run` it works.

**Long description of the problem...**

My Spring Boot app runs fine in Netbeans 9 and I need to a fat self-executable jar to deploy the app in a CentOS server. I know that Netbeans runs Spring Boot by `mvn spring-boot:run`.

In my development machine, I created two script: the first one executes Spring Boot like Netbeans does, and it works; the second tries to produce the executable jar. In the scripts I change the Java path because I have multiple versions of Java (the default is Java 10).

**First script:**

```
# Changes the current dir and remove the target dir
cd ~/Projects/AppServer/
rm -fR target

# Changes the Bash path, adding maven and replacing Java10 with Java8.
# It also set the Java home dir.
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/"
export M2_HOME=~/netbeans-9/java/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's#java-10-oracle#java-8-oracle#g')

# Execute the Spring Boot server
mvn -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 spring-boot:run
```

**Output:** (I use an external link because there is a limit of length in the body of Stack Overflow questions)
https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/e63ff919e90377e567a78e508300e186

**Second script**:

```
# Changes the current dir and remove the target dir
cd ~/Projects/AppServer/
rm -fR target

# Changes the Bash path, adding maven and replacing Java10 with Java8.
# It also set the Java home dir.
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/"
export M2_HOME=~/netbeans-9/java/maven
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's#java-10-oracle#java-8-oracle#g')

# Create a fat jar to execute the Spring Boot server
mvn -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 package spring-boot:repackage

# Tries to execute
cd target
./app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**Output**: (I use an external link because there is a limit of length in the body of Stack Overflow questions) 
https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/5b4a88b6aca5caa061eab57eed8db047

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AppServerCode</name>
    <description>Teammate</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <skip.it>true</skip.it>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId> 
            <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId> 
            <version>1.2</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
            <artifactId>aerogear-otp-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.14</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <proguardVersion>6.0.3</proguardVersion>
                    <options>
                        <option>-target 1.8</option>
                    </options>
                    <exclusions>
                        <!-- exclude the artifact  -->
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>                                                    
                    </exclusions>
                    <proguardInclude>${basedir}/src/main/resources/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>6.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skip.it}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skip.it}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <start-class>org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher</start-class>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skip.it}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ -->
```

My `proguard.conf`:

```
-dontnote
-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.example.server.app.AppApplication {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Comment: Did you execute the jar in the command line with `java -jar your_app.jar` and that's where you got the exception?

Comment: Yes, if I execute `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -jar /home/francesco/Projects/AppServer/target/app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get the same error

Comment: Not sure about the usage of proguard but is it easy to remove/disable that dependency to eliminate/isolate issues or side-effects of it?

Comment: After your suggestion, I commented the Proguard plugin in the `pom.xml`: yes, it's that the problem. Without Proguard, the fat jar works.